Why does ping show received=5 while LAN cable is disconnected?
I am wondering why ping shows receiving packets even when the LAN cable is disconnected!!!
Step 0: Set IP address of Laptop manually in same subnet as  Device IP address, same subnet mask, no gateway, DNS,..
Step 1: Ping a device connected to my laptop via RJ45 cable.

Step 2: Disconnect the RJ45 cable:

BTW: All other network ports (e.g Wi-Fi) are disconnected.
Question: Why does it receive packets while the LAN cable is disconnected? Why does it show 0% loss?

Your second screen shot shows that your own IP address is sending you the Destination Host Unreachable messages in reply to your ping requests. There is zero loss because no packets were lost. Every ping request got a response, and even though the responses were not ping replies, no packets were unaccounted for.
